# Meaning of "static declaration" comment in Windows classic sample

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, declaration

There's a [Windows classic sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/RecipePropertyHandler/RecipePropertyHandler.cpp) with the following code and comment:

```
struct PROPERTYMAP
{
    const PROPERTYKEY *pkey;    // pointer type to enable static declaration
    PCWSTR pszXPathParent;
    PCWSTR pszValueNodeName;
};

const PROPERTYMAP g_rgPROPERTYMAP[] =
{
    { &PKEY_Title,                             L"Recipe",                L"Title" },
    { &PKEY_Comment,                           L"Recipe",                L"Comments" },
    { &PKEY_Author,                            L"Recipe/Background",     L"Author" },
    { &PKEY_Keywords,                          L"Recipe/RecipeKeywords", L"Keyword" },
    { &PKEY_Microsoft_SampleRecipe_Difficulty, L"Recipe/RecipeInfo",     L"Difficulty" },
};
```

Anybody know what the comment means by "static declaration"?  Thanks for any info.

Comment: It is likely referring to the `pkey` field being declared as a `PROPERTYKEY*` pointer rather than a `PROPERTYKEY` instance.  If `pkey` were an instance instead, the declaration of `g_rgPROPERTYMAP` would not work as a single statement, and thus couldn't be used to initialize a `static` const variable.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work as a single statement?

Comment: It's a pointer so you don't have to copy that value into the mapping table.

Comment: @loop123123 To be a single statement, all fields of all elements in the array must be initialized in one go. If `pkey` were `const PROPERTYKEY` instead of `const PROPERTYKEY*`, then `g_rgPROPERTYMAP` would have to be initialized like `= { { PKEY_Title, ... }, { PKEY_Comment, ...}, ... };`, which would require the compiler to *copy* each `PKEY` into the array, which it is actually not allowed to do in a static variable initialization (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073332/65863)

Comment: Okay, so correct me if I'm wrong, but doing `const PROPERTYKEY` would compile, but the map would have to be initialized at runtime rather than compile time?

Comment: @loop123123 no, it won’t compile, since a `static` variable (or, in this case, an array) can’t be initialized by copying another variable. Did you not read the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073332/65863) I linked to?

Comment: Yes, but for me, the code above will compile without using pointers.  It just won't compile without pointers if `constexpr` is used instead.

Comment: The code (without using pointers) can be compiled in C++, but in C, you will get "error: initializer element is not constant". These classic samples contain examples of Win32 api usage, and win32 api is basically written in C. So it use the pointers type for portability.